# Custom keyboard on android?

Tags: android, keyboard

I'd like to write my own software keyboard on android.
I've found this blog post:
http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2009/04/creating-input-method.html
Also i have found `SoftwareKeyboard` sample in android samples.

I compiled apk and installed it in emulator. I've selected my keyboard in Settings / Language & Keyboard but my software keyboard is not shown when i focus any editable control in another apps. I expect to see button with text "hey!" instead of keyboard:

```
/**
 *
 */
public class KeyboardsService extends InputMethodService {

    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                200 // 200 px
        ));
        button.setText("hey!");
        view = button;

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // send "Enter" on click
                sendDownUpKeyEvents(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

So what's wrong? The same problem with `SampleKeyboard` sources - it's listed in software keyboards list but not shown. I can see default keyboard is checked and not available. Is this the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I was afraid to test it on the device but i did it. The code above works for hardware device but not in emulator. You have to install the apk, enable input method and se it as default.